how to convert below owl-carousel jquery code into pure javascript code
i know owl carousel is deprecated, i just want to know if convert below code from jquery to  pure javascript , how to do it?
function Init()  {
    var owl = $('.carousel'),
        itemsBgArray = [], // to store items background-image
        itemBGImg;
  
    owl.owlCarousel({ 
        items: 1,
        smartSpeed: 2000,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 8000,
        autoplaySpeed: 1000,
        stagePadding: 0,
        margin:0,
        loop: true,
        nav: true,
        dots:false,
        navText: false,
        onTranslated: function () {
            changeNavsThump();
        }
    });
    var owlItem = $('.owl-item'),
        owlLen = owlItem.length;
    /* --------------------------------
      * store items bg images into array
    --------------------------------- */
    $.each(owlItem, function( i, e ) {
        itemBGImg = $(e).find('.owl-item-bg').data('src');
        itemsBgArray.push(itemBGImg);
    });
    /* --------------------------------------------
      * nav control thump
      * nav control icon
    --------------------------------------------- */
    var owlNav = $('.owl-nav'),
        el;
    
    $.each(owlNav.children(), function (i,e) {
        el = $(e);
        // append navs thump/icon with control pattern(owl-prev/owl-next)
        el.append('<div class="'+ el.attr('class').match(/owl-\w{4}/) +'-thump">');
        el.append('<div class="'+ el.attr('class').match(/owl-\w{4}/) +'-icon">');
    });
    $( ".owl-prev-icon").html('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="size-12 text-primclr" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="currentColor" d="M15.41 16.58L10.83 12l4.58-4.59L14 6l-6 6l6 6z"/></svg>');
    $( ".owl-next-icon").html('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="size-12 text-primclr" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="currentColor" d="M8.59 16.58L13.17 12L8.59 7.41L10 6l6 6l-6 6z"/></svg>');
    
    /*-------------------------------------------
      Change control thump on each translate end
    ------------------------------------------- */
    function changeNavsThump() {
        var activeItemIndex = parseInt($('.owl-item.active').index()),
            prevItemIndex = activeItemIndex != 0 ? activeItemIndex - 1 : owlLen - 1,
            nextItemIndex = activeItemIndex != owlLen - 1 ? activeItemIndex + 1 : 0;
        $('.owl-prev-thump').css({
            backgroundImage: 'url(' + itemsBgArray[prevItemIndex] + ')'
        });
        $('.owl-next-thump').css({
            backgroundImage: 'url(' + itemsBgArray[nextItemIndex] + ')'
        });
    }
    changeNavsThump();
}


function Init() {
var owl = document.querySelector('.carousel');
var itemsBgArray = []; // to store items background-image
var itemBGImg;

// Initialize carousel settings
var items = owl.children;
var currentIndex = 0;

function setItemBackgrounds() {
    Array.from(items).forEach(function (item) {
        itemBGImg = item.querySelector('.owl-item-bg').getAttribute('data-src');
        itemsBgArray.push(itemBGImg);
    });
}

function createNavThumbnails() {
    var owlNav = document.querySelector('.owl-nav');
    Array.from(owlNav.children).forEach(function (nav) {
        var thumpDiv = document.createElement('div');
        thumpDiv.className = nav.className.match(/owl-\w{4}/)[0] + '-thump';
        nav.appendChild(thumpDiv);
        
        var iconDiv = document.createElement('div');
        iconDiv.className = nav.className.match(/owl-\w{4}/)[0] + '-icon';
        nav.appendChild(iconDiv);
    });

    document.querySelector('.owl-prev-icon').innerHTML = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="size-12 text-primclr" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="currentColor" d="M15.41 16.58L10.83 12l4.58-4.59L14 6l-6 6l6 6z"/></svg>';
    document.querySelector('.owl-next-icon').innerHTML = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="size-12 text-primclr" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="currentColor" d="M8.59 16.58L13.17 12L8.59 7.41L10 6l6 6l-6 6z"/></svg>';
}

function changeNavsThump() {
    var activeItemIndex = currentIndex;
    var prevItemIndex = activeItemIndex !== 0 ? activeItemIndex - 1 : items.length - 1;
    var nextItemIndex = activeItemIndex !== items.length - 1 ? activeItemIndex + 1 : 0;

    document.querySelector('.owl-prev-thump').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + itemsBgArray[prevItemIndex] + ')';
    document.querySelector('.owl-next-thump').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + itemsBgArray[nextItemIndex] + ')';
}

function showItem(index) {
    // Hide all items
    Array.from(items).forEach((item, i) => {
        item.style.display = (i === index) ? 'block' : 'none';
    });
    currentIndex = index;
    changeNavsThump();
}

// Event listeners for navigation buttons
document.querySelector('.owl-prev').addEventListener('click', function () {
    showItem((currentIndex - 1 + items.length) % items.length);
});
document.querySelector('.owl-next').addEventListener('click', function () {
    showItem((currentIndex + 1) % items.length);
});

// Initialize carousel
setItemBackgrounds();
createNavThumbnails();
showItem(currentIndex);

// Autoplay functionality
setInterval(function () {
    showItem((currentIndex + 1) % items.length);
}, 8000); // Change item every 8 seconds
 }

// Call the Init function to set up the carousel
Init();

please try to above code.
